# Magento - Resize image breaking site

Tags: php, apache, magento

For some reason the site breaks when it tries to do this:

```
<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(242) ?>
```

The site renders until that line, no errors are shown anywhere (neither apache error or log, nor system.log or exception.log).

It happens on any website of this project, I don't know if I'm missing some PHP module or something like that? On dev site it works well with the same code, so I'm not sure what could be causing it. Other projects are working well too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not seeing any errors in the Magento logs, this might be a symptom of not having PHP's GD extension enabled. I believe the resize() function uses that extension.

Check your php configuration to make sure that's enabled.

Here are the other system requirements, assuming you're using a version of Magento pre-1.9: [system requirements](http://magento.com/resources/previous-magento-system-requirements)

Comment: Thanks Brian! We posted at the same time lol. You're right it was the GD extension :)

Comment: Good stuff :) Please accept my answer if you would - trying to build a little more rep!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this installing php-gd module

```
sudo apt-get install php5-gd
```

Then

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

It fixed the problem